# Keyboard Shortcut to change specific program's volume in Windows

Tags: windows, audio, keyboard-shortcuts, volume-mixer

I was looking for a way to quickly change the volume to only one program, probably the active window, using a keyboard shortcut. I can do this manually with the Windows Volume Mixer, but I'm looked for a quicker way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Nircmd**](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html)'s [*setappvolume*](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/setappvolume.html), [*changeappvolume*](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/changeappvolume.html) and [*muteappvolume*](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/muteappvolume.html) commands are what you want.

You can create shortcuts to nircmd.exe, set keyboard shortcuts and add the following to the shortcut properties' *Target* fields:

```
setappvolume focused <volume level>
changeappvolume focused <volume level>
muteappvolume focused <mute mode>
```

where:

*volume level* is a number between 0 and 1 and stands for the percentage of change
(for *changeappvolume* it can be positive or negative)

*mute mode* is either 0 (= unmute), 1 (= mute) or 2 (= toggle between mute and unmute)